# How to find boundary of the intersection of two mesh regions in CW or CCW?

Tags: plotting, functions, function-construction, regions, computational-geometry

I have two lists of points as follow and they're not fixed.

```
ptlist1 = {{-3, 3}, {-5, 6}, {-5, 0}, {5, 0}, {5, 5}, {1, 3}, {-3, 3}};
ptlist2 = {{5, 0}, {5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {-5, 0}};
```

Now I want to find the boundary of the intersection of two mesh regions formed by these lists and then plot it using ListLinePlot.

This is what I have so far.

```
region1 = MeshRegion[#, Polygon[Range@Length@#]] &@ptlist1;
region2 = MeshRegion[#, Polygon[Range@Length@#]] &@ptlist2;
intsec= RegionIntersection[region1, region2];
intpts = MeshCoordinates[intsec] ;
ListLinePlot[intpts, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

The problem is that `MeshCoordinates` does not generate points in a way that `ListLinePlot` uses.
The first and last point are not the same so the plot by `ListLinePlot` is not closed.
Also these points may not strictly follow one specific direction such clockwise or counterclockwise so the boundary by `ListLinePlot` is not same as boundary of `intsec`.

```
{intsec, ListLinePlot[intpts, GridLines -> Automatic]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**

For another cases such as concave region, although the boundary maybe separate to several parts, but still to form a circular circle.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[53];
reg1 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Annulus[{0, 0}, {.8, 1}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 80];
pts1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2}];
reg2 = ConvexHullMesh[pts1];
bd = RegionBoundary[
   RegionIntersection[RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2]]];
bds = ConnectedMeshComponents[bd];
colors = RandomColor@Length@bds;
bdpts = MeshCoordinates /@ bds;
bdlines = MeshCells[#, "Multicells" -> True] & /@ bds;
GraphicsGrid[{{Graphics[{{Opacity[.2], Cyan, reg1}, {Opacity[.3], 
      Orange, reg2}, {bd}}], 
   Graphics[Thread[{colors, bds}]]}, {ListLinePlot[
    Append[#, First@#] & /@ bdpts, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
    PlotStyle -> colors], 
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], 
     Thread[{colors, 
       MapThread[BoundaryMeshRegion, {bdpts, bdlines}]}]}]}}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

```
Clear[pts1, pts2, bd, pts];
pts1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50, 2}];
pts2 = RandomReal[{-1.5, .8}, {50, 2}];
reg1 = ConvexHullMesh[pts1];
reg2 = ConvexHullMesh[pts2];
bd = RegionBoundary@RegionIntersection[RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2]];
pts = MeshCoordinates@bd;
Show[reg1, reg2, bd, 
 ListLinePlot[Append[pts, First@pts], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.3], AbsoluteThickness[6], Red]]]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
bd = RegionBoundary[intsec];
pts = MeshCoordinates[bd];
Show[bd, ListLinePlot[Append[pts, First@pts], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.3], AbsoluteThickness[6], Red]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, while it works in this case I don't think `Append[pts, First@pts]` always works as the points may not arranged in the order of CW or CCW.

Comment: @hana Yes, for concave region,the `bd` maybe separate to several cyclic rings. `SeedRandom[1];
reg1 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Annulus[{0, 0}, {.8, 1}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 80];
pts1 = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {20, 2}];
reg2 = ConvexHullMesh[pts1];
bd = RegionBoundary[
   RegionIntersection[RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2]]];
Graphics[{{Opacity[.2], Cyan, reg1}, {Opacity[.3], Orange, 
   reg2}, {Red, bd}}]` We can draw it by `Graphics` instead of `ListLinePlot` since `bd` is `MeshRegion`.